# Java 8 read file using streams java.io.UncheckedIOException

Tags: java, io, java-8

I am trying to use streams to read a file but I cannot get past an exception. I have been looking around but I just can't understand why it's being thrown.

The file I am going to read is `file.txt` and it's encoded with UTF-8.

I am reading it using `Files.lines()`:

```
String path = FileWordCount.class.getResource("file.txt").getPath().substring(1);

Files.lines(Paths.get(path), Charset.forName("UTF-8")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

When trying to read the file I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
[...]
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

Normally I don't post simple questions about exceptions but I just figure this one out.

Comment: Could this be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268132/all-inclusive-charset-to-avoid-java-nio-charset-malformedinputexception-input ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UncheckedIOException` is wrapping a `MalformedInputException` - that is the unlying error. The JavaDoc for that says:

> Checked exception thrown when an input byte sequence is not legal for
>   given charset, or an input character sequence is not a legal
>   sixteen-bit Unicode sequence.

So your `file.txt` does not contain valid UTF-8 and is causing the UTF-8 decoder to report an error.