# Check the Keys of an external JSON File in Java

Tags: java, json, file, parsing

as the Title states i would like to check the Keys of an external Json File in Java.

*What i tried:*

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("src/com/json/inventory.json");
System.out.println(json.keys());
```

*Issue*: Doesn't do anything.

What are other posibilities?

**Thank you in advance!**

**EDIT**
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FIOO.png)

Comment: What does `Doesn't do anything` mean ?

Comment: What is the full class name of your JSONObject ?

Comment: Gives out an Error and doesn't function

Comment: What do you mean with full class name? JSONObject json = new JSONObject("src/com/json/inventory.json"); i tried to add the path to the invetory.json - which is the .JSON File

Comment: Please edit your post and add the error stack that is printed when you execute these lines. By the way `Doesn't do anything` and `Gives out an error` isn't the same thing at all.

Comment: JSONObject doesn't handle a simple String path like that. The error you get is because the constructor `JSONObject(String)` waits for a serialized JSON, not a file path. That's why the exception says : must begin with '{'

Comment: It's not looking at the contents of the file.  It's parsing the file path you've given it as if _that_ was json.  Look at the API documentation for the `JSONObject` you're using (which is possibly why @AliceOualouest was asking for the full class name above) to find a way to do it via files (or load the file contents to a `String` using any of the normal File IO).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [this library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json), first you should read the file content like:

```
String unparsedJson = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("src/com/json/inventory.json"))
                .stream()
                .reduce((a,b) -> a + b)
                .get();
```

Then you can parse json with the code you provided:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(unparsedJson);
```

And iterate over the keys with something like this:

```
json.keys().forEachRemaining(key -> {
            System.out.println(key);
        });
```

You could also use other libraries such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: Hey, yes i do indeed Use org.json. There seem to come out an Error : "java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1" at the:  String unparsedJson = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("src/com/json/inventory.json")) - Line

Comment: It seems there are some issues with the file encoding; take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268132/all-inclusive-charset-to-avoid-java-nio-charset-malformedinputexception-input).

Answer (score 0):

1. Get JSON file from Assets Folder
2. Print all keys from JSON

-

```
private String getJSonFromAssets(){
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("colorAndValue.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}

---

try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(getJSonFromAssets());
        Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
        while(keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            System.out.println(key);
            Log.d("innerKey", "key " + key);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And your output will be like
 1. key color0
 2. key color1
 3. key color2
 4. key color3
 5. key color4
 6. key color5

Comment: There seem to be an Error getAsses().open - Method isn*t recognized. What Library do you use?